# PostgreSQL psql not start

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have Debian 9, start postgresql by unit file, in postgresql.conf listen IP - server IP address, port 5432, in pg_hba.conf

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

.

```
$ ls -la /var/run/postgresql/
total 4
drwxrwsr-x  2 postgres postgres  80 Sep  7 19:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root     root     560 Sep  7 16:22 ..
srwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   0 Sep  7 19:52 .s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  69 Sep  7 19:52 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: if i connet $psql -p 5432 it is work, the problem is - psql use wrong port by default

Answer (score 0):

`psql` on Debian determines to what PostgreSQL instance (or "cluster") it should connect to by looking at the following options or configuration variables, as documented by `man pg_wrapper`:

> The target cluster is selected by the following means, in descending
>     order of precedence:
>
> 1. explicit specification with the --host option
> 2. explicit specification with the --cluster option
> 3. if the PGHOST environment variable is set, no further cluster
>        selection is performed. The default PostgreSQL version and port
>        number (from the command line, the environment variable PGPORT, or
>        default 5432) will be used.
> 4. explicit specification with the PGCLUSTER environment variable
> 5. matching entry in ~/.postgresqlrc (see postgresqlrc(5)), if that
>        file exists
> 6. matching entry in /etc/postgresql-common/user_clusters (see
>        user_clusters(5)), if that file exists
> 7. If only one local cluster exists, that one will be selected.
> 8. If several local clusters exist, the one listening on the default
>        port 5432 will be selected.

To figure out why `psql` chooses a different port than `5432`, go through points #1 to #7, since just using port `5432` is the last thing it tries.